# Assigned static ip address doesn't retain

Tags: networking, router, ip

I changed my computer's dynamic ip address to static, but after reboot when I opened local area connection properties, then I saw IP address and subnet mask values have become empty. Then just to confirm, i typed command ipconfig in cmd, the same values were shown to what I entered in local area connection properties before rebooting my system. So my question here is how can i force my computer to keep static ip address even after reboot?

Comment: Normally those settings will will stay after a reboot. Have you tried it multiple times?
Maybe you changed a wrong adapter?

Comment: the reason it is so far because of my wifi-router?

Comment: Then have you changed the correct adapter? If you're using Wifi, you need to set the wifi adapter properties.

Comment: I think i should reserve my computer ip address in DHCP settings.

Answer (score 0):

If your router supports static dhcp addresses, assign a static dhcp lease to your computers MAC address and you will always get the same IP address every time your computer gets one from your router.